# Eclipse autogenerated toString() method

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring

As par as I know concatinate String using + sign is not a good practice when you have large number of String. But when I check on eclipse generated toString() method (Write click on source file -> Source -> Generate toString() ) it has the same.

```
public class Temp
 {
      private String tempName;
      private String tempValue;

      // here getters and setters

  /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
  */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Temp [tempName=" + tempName + ", tempValue=" + tempValue + "]";
}

}
```

Is there any place to configure like my expected toString() method like bellow in eclipse or Why the eclipse doesn't consider that.

```
   public String expectedToString(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Temp [tempName=").append(tempName).append(",").append(" tempValue=").append(tempValue).append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm going to use auto generated toString() method to log my object values.

Kindly advice me.

Comment: IIRC 1) Now the best way is using `StringBuilder` and 2) nowadays the compiler changes the `String +` to `StringBuilder` expressions. Can someone confirm it?

Comment: Using + to concatenate isn't really a problem any more.  The compiler optimizes the use of +, especially when multiple strings are involved.

Comment: Non-issue: "+" and ".append()" and ".concat()" should perform identically in this case.  Interesting links: http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/07/19/java-string-performanc/ and [Yet again on string append vs concat vs +](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962482/yet-again-on-string-append-vs-concat-vs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to change anything, it's compact and easily readable, javac will use StringBuilder for actual concatination, if you decompile your Temp.class you will see

```
public String toString() {
   return (new StringBuilder("Temp [tempName=")).append(tempName).append(", tempValue=").append(tempValue).append("]").toString();
}
```

But in other situations, like

```
    String[] a = { "1", "2", "3" };
    String str = "";
    for (String s : a) {
        str += s; 
    }
```

`+` or `+=` is a real performance killer, see decompiled code

```
String str = "";
for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    String s = args1[i];
    str = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(str))).append(s).toString();
}
```

on each iteration a new StringBuilder is created and then converted to String. Here you should use StringBuilder explictily

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : a) {
        sb.append(s); 
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Eclipse 4.21 (Jul. 2021, 9 years later) would facilitate the production of the right code with:

> ### ["Use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer" clean up](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.21/jdt.php#stringbuffer-to-stringbuilder)

> A new clean up has been added that converts code to use `StringBuilder` (added in Java 1.5) rather than `StringBuffer` which has synchronized methods and is slower than using `StringBuilder`.
>
> There is a sub-option where changes will only occur to local variables which is on by default.
> When this sub-option is on, changes will only occur to `StringBuffer` variables that are local to a method.
> When a method calls other methods with such variables or assigns to/from fields/parameters, the method contents will not be converted.
> It is permitted to append StringBuffer fields or parameters to local `StringBuffer` variables which can then still be converted to `StringBuilder`.
>
> When the option is selected and the sub-option for local variables is off,all usage of `StringBuffer` in the selected files are changed to `StringBuilder` regardless of usage.
> It should be noted that in this case, the clean up will not track down non-selected classes and methods that are referenced and might require changes to compile successfully.
>
> To apply the clean up, select the `Use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer` check box on the `Optimization` tab in your clean up profile.
> To specify just for local variables, select the `Only for local variables` check box found just below.
>
> [image: Preferences -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.21/images/stringbuffer-to-stringbuilder-prefs.png]

Example:

[image: Before -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.21/images/stringbuffer-to-stringbuilder-before.png]

Would become:

[image: After -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.21/images/stringbuffer-to-stringbuilder-after.png]